# How to draw an alternating line with pyplot?

Tags: matplotlib, line

I have a series of x coordinates (e.g.: 1,2,3,4) and y coordinates (e.g.: 10,20,30,40). I would like pyplot to draw a line between two consecutive points, while skipping every other line (e.g.: draw a line between (1,10) and (2,20), and a line between (3,30) and (4,40).)
How can this be done?

Comment: The quick and dirty trick would be to insert NaN values in the arrays at every third position (both X and Y).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Copied from @Floris' comment above)

The quick and dirty trick would be to insert NaN values in the arrays at every third position (both X and Y).

Comment: The standard etiquette here when copying a comment (not your own) as an answer is to mark the answer as community wiki.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
y = [10,20,30,40,50,60]

for n in np.arange(0,len(x),2):
    plt.plot(x[n:n+2],y[n:n+2])
```

[image]

Comment: Would that be slow for many segments, because of the Python loop?

Comment: Yes it would be. I think Floris' suggestion would be alot faster in a situation where you have hunderds or more segments.